# Java Thread safety questions

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, thread-safety

I bumped into an exercise and I am no java guru to know how to implement that. My objective is to implement a generic interface, that has a getter and setter method. In It's constructor I have to put an s object that implements this generic interface. We have to Store this object in our class and use this class's getter and setters to implement our classes getters and setters(delegation).

```
public class Threads<T> implements Buffer<T>{
    Object s;
    public Threads(Object s) { // we know, that It implements our Buffer interface
        this.s=s;//i have no clue to what I should convert it.
    }
    
    synchronized public void put(T t) {
        //i don't know how to call s's put method
    }
    synchronized public T get() {
        //I don't know how to call s's get method.
        
    }
    
}
```

My question is: how do I deal with the parts of the code above where I have indicated in the comments that I don't know what to write?

Any ideas?

Comment: If you have two questions, you should ask them separately.

Comment: @Makkador - I will make a bargain with you.  Edit your Question to delete one of the questions and I will then try to understand and answer the other one.  Otherwise, the Question is liable to be closed ... without any answers.

Comment: Good lad ... :-)

Comment: I rolled back the edit and edited so the first question is asked, because your previous edit did not ask a question.

Comment: I have rolled back your rollback because it has rendered my Answer to the revised question meaningless.  Mark - you ought to know better!  There are clear questions asked.  Look at the code comments.   The only thing that is missing is the question marks.  I will add them ... if it makes you happy.

Comment: @StephenC I don't see what the question is, so I have voted to close.

Comment: The question is.  "Do I code the bits that I have commented to indicate that I don't know what to do?"  Is that now clear enough for you?

Comment: You tagged this question "multithreading," "synchronization," and "thread-safety" even though there's nothing in it that relates to threads in any way. I'm guessing that your "exercise" must have come from some tutorial that eventually will teach you something about threads. But, be careful! When it comes to threads, there's a lot of bad advice out there. I can't guess what the tutorial might evolve that `Threads<T>` class into, but all by itself, it [_smells funny_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell). Keep your eyes open, and come back when you have more questions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume that the "it" you refer to is the `s` parameter.

You need to declare the `s` parameter and `s` field with type `Buffer<T>`.  Something like this:

```
public class Threads<T> implements Buffer<T>{
    Buffer<T> s;

    public Threads(Buffer<T> s) { 
        this.s = s;
    }
    
    synchronized public void put(T t) {
        s.put(t);
    }

    synchronized public T get() {
        return s.get();
    }
}
```

At this point you have implemented a thread-safe wrapper for a `Buffer<T>`.  But it is only thread safe with respect to operations performed using the wrapper methods.

(This `Buffer<T>` class / interface must be something that you have designed yourself.  The standard `java.nio.Buffer` class isn't parameterized, and it doesn't provide `get` and `put` methods.  The subclasses of `java.nio.Buffer` do have `get` and `put` methods, but they are not related to each other at the type level.)